# Is it possible to get partial response using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code

```
 $url = "partial_response.php";
 $sac_curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
 curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 11);
 $resp = curl_exec($sac_curl); 
 curl_close($sac_curl);
 echo $resp;
```

Partial_response.php

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Job waiting ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i &#60; 10 ; $i++ )
{
echo $i . '<br/>';
flush();
ob_flush();
sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br/>';
```

From the about code am trying to get a partial response from partial_response.php. what I want is, I need  curl to return me "Job waiting.." alone instead of waiting for the partial_response.php to complete the loop and return the entire data. so when I reduce CURLOPT_TIMEOUT below 11 i dont get any response at all. Kindly clarify my doubt.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is not at the end of *getting* the response, but at the end of *sending* it. I think since your `Partial_response.php` sends data at the end of it's execution, you never get it with low timeout (it does not reach it's end, so data is not sent). Try `flush()` function alone or in conjunction with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to recieve partial output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I later realized that cURL could not do what I want, I used  `stream_context_get_options`
to achieve what I wanted. Here it is, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-get-options.php.

Comment: This is not an answer, please explain how you solved the issue using stream_context_get_options

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid not. At least not that I know of any, this is simply because PHP is a synchronous language, meaning you cannot "skip" tasks. (I.e. `curl_exec()` will always - no matter what - be executed until the request is completed)

Comment: Thats fine, can anybody tell me is there any otherway to solve this problem using php?

Comment: This is not true. Curl gets the data in sequence of iterations, every one of them returning some amount of data (this gets obvious if you think about grabbing big file/page). You can use `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to save partial data from the request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure abut the timeout, but you can get partial response using cURL by using the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION flag:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $callback);
```

Where `$ch` is the Curl handler, and `$callback` is the callback function name. This command will stream response data from remote site. The callback function can look something like:

```php
$result = '';
$callback = function ($ch, $str) {
    global $result;
    //$str has the chunks of data streamed back. 
    $result .= $str;
    // here you can mess with the stream data either with $result or $str.
    // i.e. look for the "Job waiting" string and terminate the response.
    return strlen($str);//don't touch this
};
```

If not interrupted at the end `$result` will contain all the response from remote site.

So combining everything will look something like:

```php
$result = '';
$callback = function ($ch, $str) {
    global $result;
    //$str has the chunks of data streamed back. 
    $result .= $str;
    // here you can mess with the stream data either with $result or $str.
    // i.e. look for the "Job waiting" string and terminate the response.
    return strlen($str);//don't touch this
};

$url = "partial_response.php";
$sac_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 11);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $callback);
curl_exec($sac_curl); // the response is now in $result.
curl_close($sac_curl);
echo $result;
```